# firefox: don't save error pages in history

Tags: firefox, browser, history, www

Can I configure Firefox so that error pages are not kept in the history?

If I enter once a mistaken URL, say superus**re**.com, it is kept in my history. Every time I start typing *supe...* it is suggested to me as a completion and I return to the inexisting page.

Very annoying - I think there should be a configuration option (a plugin perhaps) to tell firefox not to keep error pages in the history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible by default and doesn't know an addon for this but, when you start typing the URL in the address bar, highlight the wrong URL (with the Up and Down arrows) and press Delete. It will remove the URL from the History and it won't be proposed again as a suggestion.

Comment: The same works (sometimes while holding Shift or some other modifier key) in other browsers. It also works for entries in forms, like typos in usernames in login forms.

Comment: "Server not found" error pages are not kept in the history. For error pages returned by the web site, there's no way for Firefox to distinguish them from "good" pages.

Comment: @harrymc, good point. True error pages returned by a web site might not be kept either, *if* the server correctly includes some 404 Not Found status code, rather than an error message with 200 OK.